# Executing the content in a file (Unix)

Tags: shell, variables, unix, ksh, mailx

I have file which has the following data

```
echo Hello "$Name" How are you
```

And in the master script Name is assigned to a string. I am trying to execute the content in file so that $Name can be taken from the master script as follows

```
Name=TEST
a=$(cat abc.txt)
b=`$a`
echo b | mailx
```

when I'm trying to do as above the value for $Name is not reflecting.

The output is as follows in the mail

```
Hello "$Name" How are you
```

Please help me if im doing anything wrong

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely trust that there are no malicious commands in abc.txt, do this:

```
Name=TEST
source abc.txt | mailx
```

Otherwise, to substitute the values a bit more safely, do this:

```
export Name  # and any other variables
perl -pe 's/\$(\w+)/$ENV{$1}/g' abc.txt | mailx
```